# Product of Riemannian manifolds and volume element

Tags: riemannian-geometry, volume, product-space

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Riemannian manifolds and consider a function
\begin{align}
f\colon X\times Y &\to \mathbb{R},\\
           (x,y) &\mapsto f(x,y)
\end{align}
Now I have to integrate $f$ with respect to the Riemannian volume element of $X\times Y$. Is the infinitesimal volume element of $X\times Y$ the product of the infinitesimal volume elements of $X$ and $Y$?

My question could sound very naïve, but it is the first time that I work with Riemannian spaces and I couldn't find it in any textbooks.

Comment: ${{{{{}}}}}$yes

Comment: Thank you! Could you suggest me a reference where I can find this result?

Comment: The volume form on $X\times Y$ is the wedge product of the pullbacks of the volume forms on $X$ and $Y$ by the projections $X\times Y \to X, Y$.

Comment: sorry, now reference - but if you have a vector space $V$ with an inner product (say $V=T_xX$) and another such space $W$ ($=T_yY$), and if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is a ON basis of $V$ and $E_1,\dots E_m$ a ON basis of $W$, then $e_1,\dots,e_n,E_1,\dots,E_m$ is an ON basis of $V\oplus W$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner: Could you provide me a reference for the result you mentioned?

Comment: Any introductory differential geometry book or class notes. I would recommend Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds for the basics.